# Transforming from singly linked list to doubly by changing the connections

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a `doubly linked list` that simulates the behavior of a `singly linked list`. So I have a left, right and info but the left is always null. Something like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
```

What I want is to change it back into doubly without recreating the nodes, just by parsing the list and remaking the connections.

```
1 -> <- 2 -><- 3 -><- 4
```

I have

```
class Node {
    private int info;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
```

And my method:

```
static Node toDoublyLinked(Node root) {
        if (root.getRight() != null) {
            root.getRight().setLeft(root);
            return toDoublyLinked(root.getRight());
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Which doesn't work. It makes my program to throw stack overflow because when I connect 2 to 1, 1 already has connections to 2-> 3 -> 4 so it will start duplication that piece of list over and over which is not what I want.

Is there any solution to solving this?

```
void add(int info) {
        Node s = new Node();
        if (this.info == 0) {
            this.info = info;
        } else {
            if (info < this.info) {
                if (left != null) {
                    left.add(info);
                } else {
                    s.setInfo(info);
                    this.left = s;
                }
            } else {
                if (right != null) {
                    right.add(info);
                } else {
                    s.setInfo(info);
                    this.right = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(int info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" +
                "info=" + info +
                ", left=" + left +
                ", right=" + right +
                '}';
    }
```

Ok after some more debugging, it seems that it does throw StackOverflow in the toDoublyLinked but in the toString method. Why is it even calling toString in that method? I'm not. Not explicitly at least. I can understand why the toString is wrongly made but even if I comment it, it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: I think what you have here looks right. However we would need the setLeft() and getRight() code to help you.

Comment: I don't understand the sense behind the first *return* in toDoublyLinked(). If you call that method on your "real" root ... wouldn't that method in the end return the right-most node? What is the point in doing so?

Comment: One problem here is having a method instead of a procedure here is that you  are taking as argument the leftmost node of the list, but returning (after the modifications) the rightmost node.

Comment: Also, Java doesn't have tail recursion optimization,  so your code WILL stack overflow on reasonably long lists. Use iteration instead.

Comment: Ok. I want to return the leftMostNode again. I thought that by doing it recursively, somehow... it would give me the right result. It makes sense what you're saying. So how can I change my method so it does what it's supposed to and returns the leftmost node?

Comment: @Mocktheduck I guess the point is: *any* node that you give as argument to that method will be the leftmost node afterwards anyway. So why should the method return anything anyway? You call the method on the left end of your "single linked" list; and afterwards, the left end ... is the root for a "double linked" list. So need for a return at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void toDoublyLinked(Node node) {
    Node current = node;
    while (current.getRight() != null) {
        current.getRight().setLeft(current);
        current = current.getRight();
    }
}
```

If you want recursion:

```
public static void toDoublyLinked(Node node) {
    if (node.getRight() != null) {
         node.getRight().setLeft(node);
         toDoublyLinked(node.getRight());
    }
}
```

but remember that, as I said before, since Java doesn't have tail recursion optimization, this WILL stack overflow on long lists even though it's technically and ideologically correct;

Comment: Ok I should've mentioned. I want to not use any additional variables. That's why I was trying recursion, to just return the finally solved list

Comment: Edited to include the answer for completeness (along with the comment  why it's a bad idea in Java)

Comment: @PiotrWilkin oops did not see the need for no additional variables in my answer. Thus this should be the accepted answer. +1 for mentioning why it's bad anyway.

Comment: since java is not pass-by-reference but pass-by-copy-of-reference, will anything toDoublyLinked does to node have any effect on my initial node?

Comment: Of course, because technically the dot operator in Java behaves like the arrow operator in C++ (i.e. `node.getRight()` is really `(*node).getRight()`, so it doesn't matter if technically `node != nodeCopy` if it's true that `(*node) == (*nodeCopy)` (which it is).

Comment: The only thing that you *cannot do* with pass-by-reference-copy is modify the original reference via called method - so if you have:

    Node foo = <something>;
    StaticClass.method(foo);

and `StaticClass.method(...)` has:

     `public static void method(Node ref) {
         ref = new Node();
     }`

then this will have no impact on `foo`.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. You are right. It works this way. It really helped me understand how pass-by-reference-copy works.

Comment: @Mocktheduck: why do you want to not use any additional variables? Some esoteric programming style guide? And performing the same `node.getRight()` call three times consecutively is better?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use recursion that will cause Stack Overflow over long lists.
What you should do instead is use an iterative method such as:

```
public static void toDoublyLinked(Node node){
    Node currentNode = node ;
    while(currentNode.getRight() !=null){
         currentNode.getRight().setLeft(currentNode);
         currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
    }
}
```

This way, your code will not cause a stack overflow no matter the length of the list. Sure you have an additional variable but you will avoid the stack overflow with long lists AND improve the complexity (calling a function costs more).

However, if you still want to only use recursion (even though you should not), here is a piece of code:

```
public static void toDoublyLinked(Node node) {
    if (node.getRight() != null) {
         node.getRight().setLeft(node);
         toDoublyLinked(node.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is true; but thats a bit like cheating - he is asking how to fix his recursion ... not how to get rid of it.

Comment: @GhostCat he was not asking this in his initial question. So I thought it would be better to go for the best solution. After seeing the answer by Piotr I said it should be the accepted answer since it has all the *new* requirements that OP asked for. Can still update my answer though you're right